# Editing an external Propery List (.plist)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, plist, external

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

}

- (IBAction)unlockIt:(id)sender {

    if ([[appField stringValue] length] < 1) {
        [status setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        [status setStringValue:@"error with name"];
    }
    else {
        [status setStringValue:@""];
        [status setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];

        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Applications/%@.app/Contents", [appField stringValue]];

        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path]; 

        NSString *infoPlist = [bundle pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSString *randomIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.derp.%i", arc4random()];

        [infoPlist setValue:randomIdentifier forKey:@"Bundle identifier"];

        [status setStringValue:@"attempt successful"];
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Bundle identifier.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key isn’t ‘Bundle identifier’ — that’s the friendly representation of the key.

The actual key is ‘CFBundleIdentifier’, and there’s a `CFStringRef` constant for it that you can cast to an `NSString`:

```
(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey
```

---

**Edit:** More issues with your code:

```
NSString *infoPlist = [bundle pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
[infoPlist setValue:randomIdentifier forKey:@"Bundle identifier"];
```

`infoPlist` is a string containing that file path of the Info.plist file inside an application bundle. It is not the plist itself. You need to read Info.plist into a dictionary, change its contents, and then write it again. For example:

```
NSString *infoPlistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *infoPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:infoPlistPath];
[infoPlist setObject:randomIdentifier forKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey];
[infoPlist writeToFile:infoPlistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I still get `setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CFBundleIdentifier.`...